Julia sets of $z^2 + c$ with alternating $c$, mandelbrot set with parameters
Introduction
I was inspired by a friend to play around with variations on the julia set for the classic map $z \to z^2 + c$. With the classic Lypunov logistic fractal in mind the idea was to alternate the value of $c$ between even and odd iterations. This is equivalent to iterating the map $z \to (z^2 + c_1)^2 + c_2 = z^4 + 2z^2c_1 + c_1^2 + c_2$.
For a pure julia set, both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two complex parameters, and to render the julia set we iterate some complex $z_0$ and color it based on the escape time (stopped iteration when $|z_i| \geq 4$ or when $i \geq n$ for some large $n$, then color based on $i$). The julia sets are aesthetically pleasing, as is common. I've called them $J(c_1, c_2)$ because of the two free parameters. If you flip the roles of the two parameters, the set would be $J(c_2, c_1)$, which usually does look slightly different.
There is also the possibility of creating a mix between the mandelbrot set and the julia set. In this case we have four possibilities based on the two parameters, which I have named as follows:
$$M(c_1):~z \to (z^2 + c)^2 + c_1$$ $$M'(c_1):~z \to (z^2 + c_1)^2 + c$$ $$M(c_2):~z \to (z^2 + c)^2 + c_2$$ $$M'(c_2):~z \to (z^2 + c_2)^2 + c$$
When setting $c_1 = c_2 = z_0$ we just get the classic mandelbrot set $M$ but perform two iterations at once.
What I observed
For the classic map $z \to z^2 + c$ the julia sets either are completely connected, in which case they may or may not contain islands inside them (Examples: For $c = 0$ the julia set is a circle and contains an island, but for $c = -2$ is it a straight line segment without interior or for $c = i$ it is a lighting-like structure without interior, but connected.) or they are fragmented into dust, in which case there is no interior (Example: $c = 0.5$).
It is also known (I believe) that the julia set is connected if the point $c$ is in the mandelbrot set and that it is fragmented into dust if $c$ isn't in the mandelbrot set.
Notably the julia set can't be fragmented and have an interior, that is islands. For the map in question here, this is possible, and from playing around it seems to me that this occurs if and only if either $c_1 \in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \not\in M(c_1)$ or $c_1 \not\in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \in M(c_1)$. The other two cases mirror the classic map in that both $c_1 \in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \in M(c_1)$ leads to a completely connected julia set and $c_1 \not\in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \not\in M(c_1)$ leads to dust without interior. So to recap:
$$c_1 \in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \in M(c_1) :\quad J(c_1, c_2)~\text{and}~J(c_2, c_1)~\text{totally connected, can have interior}$$
$$c_1 \in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \not\in M(c_1) :\quad J(c_1, c_2)~\text{and}~J(c_2, c_1)~\text{fragmented into islands, can have interior}$$
$$c_1 \not\in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \in M(c_1) :\quad J(c_1, c_2)~\text{and}~J(c_2, c_1)~\text{fragmented into islands, can have interior}$$
$$c_1 \not\in M(c_2)~\land~c_2 \not\in M(c_1) :\quad J(c_1, c_2)~\text{and}~J(c_2, c_1)~\text{fragmented into dust, no interior}$$
I haven't found any exceptions by looking at a variety of random examples but have no idea how one would formalize this notion.
Another thing I observed was $c_1 \in M \leftrightarrow c_1 \in M(c_1)$ and $c_2 \in M \leftrightarrow c_2 \in M(c_2)$, which is somewhat trivial, because in that particular point their iteration formulas end up identical. I don't know if this has any ramifications.
Another thing I noticed was that $c_1 \in M(c_2) \leftrightarrow c_2 \in M'(c_1)$ and $c_2 \in M(c_1) \leftrightarrow c_1 \in M'(c_2)$, which is also trivial if you plug the values into the formulas. Nonetheless this relationship is useful because it means you can pick some arbitrary $c_1$, then compute $M(c_1)$ and $M'(c_1)$ and pick the value of $c_2$ based on these plots, which gives you full control over how the julia set looks. (Otherwise both sets would depend on each others parameters and picking one becomes annoying.)
Some example plots that show the different behaviour described above: (The points $c_1$ and $c_2$ are shown in the mandelbrot views in green when they are in the set and pink if they aren't, also the imaginary axis is pointing down, classic mistake, sorry. Axis range from -2 to 2.)
$$c_1 = -0.102+0.828i,~ c_2 = 0.810+0.582i$$

$$c_1 = -0.25155795+0.004885681i,~ c_2 = -0.8748981+0.03848663i$$

$$c_1 = -0.5126952-0.11730869i,~ c_2 = 0.20672332-0.58003414i$$

The code that made these was written in processing and can be accessed here: https://pastebin.com/WpNn3vcV
Further questions
My main question is if this system in particular and julia sets with alternating or more generally non-constant parameters have been investigated. Frankly I don't even know what to search for.
Another question would be whether my observations about the sets are correct. Why is $J(c_1, c_2)$ or its counterpart fragmented into various islands (but still are locally conntected, so are not dust) when exactly one of the parameters is contained in the mandelbrot set of the other?
Then you can sort of observe that the location of $c_1$ and $c_2$ in each others mandelbrot sets result in similar features as a julia set inside a normal mandelbrot, that is for example points close to the tip of $M$ result in needle features in $J(c)$ (which I think is called being locally similar?), so that if $c_1$ is close to a tip of a minimandelbrot inside $M(c_2)$ it will also impart needle features onto $J(c_1, c_2)$. It doesn't just mix the features that those parameters would usually generate in the classic julia set together. Why those sets and parameter combinations in particular? Why do the features get combined? I know this very vaguely phrased.
What is known for the generalizations, that is what if the parameter is varied not in a $2$-cycle, but an $n$-cycle? What would be the general way to determine upfront what the general shape of the julia set will be (connected, fragmented, with islands that contain area, etc)?
